# WDF UMDF driver install problem in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, driver, wdf, umdf

I have a simple user mode usb driver that is installing and working fine in Windows XP 32 bit and Windows 7 64 bit, but for some reason fails to install correctly in Windows 7 32 bit. Do I need 2 separate drivers for XP 32bit and win7 32bit? I was under the impression that i did not.
The inf file i use is listed below:

Update 6/10/2011, I've reworked the inf file as follows, seems to work in windows7 now, but on xp it asks me where /x86 is, when I give it a path, it prepends a \ to the begining, then i delete it and it works fine. I register the .inf file with windows using:

```
SetupCopyOEMInf(infFullPath, "", OemSourceMediaType.SPOST_PATH, 0, oemName, 255, ref temp, null))
```

infFullPath is the location under program files where I copy the driver package.
Can anyone see why this wouldn't work
I store the files as follows:

AbcRadio.inf
\x86\AbcRadio.dll
\x86\WudfUpdate_01009.dll
\x86\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
\x86\WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll
\x64\AbcRadio.dll
\x64\WudfUpdate_01009.dll
\x64\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
\x64\WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll

```
;
; AbcRadio.inf - Install the AbcRadio USB user-mode driver
;

[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=Radio
ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171}
Provider=%MSFTUMDF%
DriverVer=06/09/2011,6.1.7600.16385
CatalogFile=wudf.cat

; ================== Class section ==================

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg=SampleClass_RegistryAdd

[SampleClass_RegistryAdd]
HKR,,,,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,"-10"

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========

[Manufacturer]
%MSFTUMDF%=Abc,NTX86,NTAMD64

[Abc.NTX86]
%AbcRadioUsbDeviceName%=AbcRadioUsb_Install, USB\VID_16D4&PID_1002
%AbcRadioUsbDeviceName%=AbcRadioUsb_Install, USB\VID_16D4&PID_1004

[Abc.NTAMD64]
%AbcRadioUsbDeviceName%=AbcRadioUsb_Install, USB\VID_16D4&PID_1002
%AbcRadioUsbDeviceName%=AbcRadioUsb_Install, USB\VID_16D4&PID_1004

; =================== Installation ===================

[AbcRadioUsb_Install]
CopyFiles=UMDriverCopy
Include=WINUSB.INF          ; Import installation sections from WINUSB.INF
Needs=WINUSB.NT             ; Run the CopyFiles & AddReg directives for WinUsb.INF

[AbcRadioUsb_Install.Services]
AddService=WUDFRd,0x000001fa,WUDFRD_ServiceInstall  ; flag 0x2 sets this as the service for the device
AddService=WinUsb,0x000001f8,WinUsb_ServiceInstall  ; this service is installed because its a filter.

[WinUsb_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUsb_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys
LoadOrderGroup  = Base

[WUDFRD_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName = %WudfRdDisplayName%
ServiceType = 1
StartType = 3
ErrorControl = 1
ServiceBinary = %12%\WUDFRd.sys
LoadOrderGroup = Base

[AbcRadioUsb_Install.Wdf]
UmdfDispatcher = WinUsb
UmdfService = AbcRadio, WUDFAbcRadioUsbDriver_Install
UmdfServiceOrder = AbcRadio
KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUsb_Install

[WinUsb_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion = 1.9

[AbcRadioUsb_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg=CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles=CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[AbcRadioUsb_Install.hw]
AddReg=AbcRadioUsb_Device_AddReg

[AbcRadioUsb_Device_AddReg]
HKR,,"LowerFilters",0x00010008,"WinUsb" ; FLG_ADDREG_TYPE_MULTI_SZ | FLG_ADDREG_APPEND

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WudfUpdate_01009.dll", "WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll", "WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[WUDFAbcRadioUsbDriver_Install]
UmdfLibraryVersion=1.9.0
DriverCLSID="{7bf5cb94-b686-4721-955e-878e48933a2c}"
ServiceBinary=%12%\UMDF\AbcRadio.dll

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WudfUpdate_01009.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll

[UMDriverCopy]
AbcRadio.dll

[DestinationDirs]
UMDriverCopy=12,UMDF        ; copy to drivers\umdf
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11   ; copy to system32

; ================= Source Media Section =====================

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %MediaDescription%,,,

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
AbcRadio.dll=1,x86
WudfUpdate_01009.dll=1,x86
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll=1,x86
WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll=1,x86

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
AbcRadio.dll=1,x64
WudfUpdate_01009.dll=1,x64
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll=1,x64
WinUsbCoinstaller2.dll=1,x64

; =================== Generic ==================================

[Strings]
MSFTUMDF="Abc (WDF:UMDF)"
MediaDescription="Abc Media"
ClassName="Radio"
WudfRdDisplayName="Abc WDF:UMDF Radio"
AbcRadioUsbDeviceName="Abc Radio Alpha 6/10/2011 8:53 AM"
WinUsb_SvcDesc="WinUSB Driver"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I didnt read the documentation for SetupCopyOEMInf() fully. The following line in my installer solved the final problem:
    SetupCopyOEMInf(infFullPath, installPath, OemSourceMediaType.SPOST_PATH, 0, oemName, 255, ref temp, null)

It seems that windows 7 guesses that your source disk is the location where the inf file is, if you dont specify the OEMSourceMediaLocation parameter. Windows XP does not do this, so it needs to be populated if you want Windows to know where to look for your driver.